# Navigating across main scenes in React Native Router Flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using RNRF library to navigate across screens in my app. I have a token-based authentication mechanism and I want to sign the user out whenever they click on Logout and delete the token saved in AsyncStorage.

My Router file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux'

const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                <Scene key="auth">
                    <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" initial />
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="main" hideNavBar>
                    <Scene 
                        key="tabbar" 
                        tabs
                        tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
                        showLabel={false}
                    >
                        <Scene key='homeTab' title="Home" icon={TabIcon} initial>
                            <Scene 
                                key="home"
                                component={Home}
                            />
                        </Scene>
                        <Scene key='moreTab' title="More" icon={TabIcon}>
                            <Scene 
                                key="more"
                                component={More}
                                title="More"
                            />
                        </Scene>
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

My logout button is in the More screen - which is nested inside a Tabbar scene. How do I navigate from More to Login screen so it does not look like a new login screen is pushed in from the right?

More component file -

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Button } from './common';

class More extends Component {
    onButtonPress() {
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('token').then(() => {
            Actions.popTo('login');
        });   
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Logout</Button>
        );
    }   
}

export default More;
```

Actions.popTo('login') doesn't seem to work. Do I need to restructure my Router file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Actions.auth({ type: 'reset'})`

This will reset your stack back to root.

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thank you Kelok
Only thing I had to change was - Actions.auth({ type: 'reset'}) - since I guess 'login' is a sub-scene of 'auth'

Comment: No worries. I have edited my post. Do mark it as answer so it can help others as well :)